# Open External Link On New Full Screen Window

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried to make an external link open in a full-screen window. I found this code

```
<a onclick="window.open(document.URL, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');">Link</a>
```

But it has a fixed size of a window and I can't make it full-screen.

How to make it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing `height=570,width=520`

Comment: It cannot open this link